# Converting image to a buffer string with CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am creating an e-mail form where I can attach images as attachment. Currently I am uploading the files to a temporary directory and deleting the images aftewards like this:

```
$config['upload_path']          = './temp/';
$config['allowed_types']        = 'gif|jpg|png';
$config['max_size']             = 100;
$config['max_width']            = 1024;
$config['max_height']           = 768;

$this->load->library('upload', $config);
```

I am trying, however, to save the image into a buffer string, attach that to the e-mail as the Userguide describes:

```
$this->email->attach($buffer, 'attachment', 'report.pdf', 'application/pdf');
```

I am stuck getting the image data to a string.

Any suggestions? I cannot really find anything.

Comment: Allowed types are gif, jpg and png, but the attachment is a pdf?

Comment: The last line, is as said, from the userguide to show how to attach a buffer.

Comment: That's fine, but in the future it helps if you show the code you are actually using/trying instead of documentation examples.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I don't think you need to use a buffer. Just attach the file via it's uploaded file name/path.

```
$this->email->attach($this->upload->data('full_path'), 'attachment', 'report.pdf', 'application/pdf');
```

Reference: [Email class :: attach()](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/email.html#CI_Email::attach), [Upload class :: data()](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/file_uploading.html#CI_Upload::data)

Comment: I do, however, not want to upload the image to the server to begin with. I want to post the form as is without uploading.

Comment: Now you've lost me. So you mean you were uploading before and now you don't want to use file uploading? Is the attachment the same for every email?